# Views does not open in live MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publishing

After I published my application none of links works in web site except default.aspx. When I clicked them "page not found" is shown. I guess, it is about routing. But I did not do any change on  default mvc routing settings. What could cause this kind of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verify that IIS which hosts your published web site has all the correct settings to run ASP.NET MVC (see [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) for on how to set up IIS 6 and [this](http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2008/10/07/deploying-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application-to-iis7.aspx) for IIS 7).

Answer (score 0):

One would need more details to debug the issue. On a quicker note, first check for server logs (IIS/Apache) - it would indicate whether the request reached the server or not, where was the requested routed to, who processed it and what happened. Also check for server error logs.